# Facebook4j Getting the id of who is posting a comment

Tags: java, facebook4j

Good morning. Actually I was using netvizz to get data from some pages, but I need more information than what I get. Now, I have the id_comment, and I need the id of the user who posted this comment.

I'm using this code and I need to know who posted the comment which is returned

```
public class RecuperationFacebook {

    public static String appId = "myAppId";   // Sample values
    public static String appSecret = "myAppSecret";
    public static String access_token = "myToken";

    public static Facebook facebook;

    public RecuperationFacebook() {
        facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
        facebook.setOAuthAppId(appId, appSecret);
        facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(access_token));
    }

    public static Comment Commentaire(String id_comment) throws FacebookException {
        Comment commentaire =facebook.getComment(id_comment, null);
        return(commentaire);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the method 'getFrom' in the object Comment?

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thant youuu

Comment: By the way, Moncef, do not publish your connection data (access_token et al). Keep it secret. ;-P